# Is it possibly to specify Postgres column storage type at table creation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can one specify the EXTENDED storage type for a column as part of CREATE TABLE?  If yes, would it also work under Postgres 8.1?

I don't see a way to do this except through ALTER TABLE, which seems weird for something that really belongs with the rest of the table definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don' think you can.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html

"Each TOAST-able data type specifies a default strategy for columns of that data type, but the strategy for a given table column can be altered with ALTER TABLE SET STORAGE."